# Copy Word DOM Structure As C# Object

Tags: c#, vba, ms-word

How is it possible to copy a Microsoft Word DOM structure as a C# object?

Accessing Work DOM objects is slow, and if the structure is large enough, accessing individual elements becomes prohibitively slow. For example:

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range item in myDocument.range.SpellingErrors)
{
    string myString = item.Text;
}
```

might take too long of time. You don't own the DOM object and so you can't modify for other copy techniques.

Is there a way to copy this as a C# object and then be able to work with it outside of Word?

Comment: If accessing the COM object is slow, then copying it will be just as slow.

Comment: What does this have to do with VBA?

Comment: If it's not necessary to interact with the user look at working directly with the file, using the Open XML file format (OPen XML SDK, for example). That will be much faster

Comment: OpenXML can't be used since they are not formal items in the file. Some structures exist only in memory, such as the misspelling list. This may not be a VBA question per se, other than I can't get to the DOM except through VBA. It's slow because accessing the DOM requires going through several layers.

Comment: We use Aspose at work, but it isn't free.  It is, however, pretty good.

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://forums.windowssecrets.com/showthread.php/183850-Word-VBA-Speed-Up-DOM-Object-Access 
For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: Can you get what you need from unzipping the Word Doc, and read in the XML file(s) async?

Comment: @RyanWildry I can get some information from the XML file. For example, in this case can get the misspelled words from the XML, useful, yes, but the SpellingErrors collection has more and dynamic information. There are many other in-memory collections, too.